# Exact Target : REST API. Task in salesforce to track mail

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud

I am sending a triggered send  email through exact Target. to track these mails i want to create a task in salesforce for each mail sent.

I have seen this as normal behaviour when we send it manually through salesforce.

Please let us know if it makes sense.

Comment: Not really sure what your question is.

Comment: Humm.. Ok. Normally when we send an email from salesforce using Exact Target App (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZkSEAU) it creates a Task in Activity history. in the description of the task it has Body of the email is tracked in salesforce. can we get the same if we do a triggered send in salesforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Salesforce account is integrated with ExactTarget then the CreateSalesforceObject() AMPScript function could be included in the email which could create any SF object:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/

Comment: ok now got to know that its not tracked on Task, but an object "Individual Email Result" in ampscript how can we get the following Where 
Email Name :ettest
Lead :Test Test, Test Test
From Name : Pravin
From Address :xxxx@cccc.com
Subject Line :ettest
Date Sent :2/12/2014 1:41 AM
Opened : Not Checked
Date Opened
Date Unsubscribed 
Number of Total Clicks :0
Date Bounced: 
Number of Unique Clicks :0
Link "View Sent Email" all this is tracked.  how can we do the same for triggered send email from sf

Comment: I think the formatting didn't come through on your question as it is very hard to read. I am not sure what is being asked.

Comment: see if this makes it readable: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/exact-target-rest-api-individual-email-result-in-salesforce-to-track-mail