# Exact Target : REST API. "Individual Email Result" in salesforce to track mail

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, fuel

Related to previous Question:
[My Previous Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27488/exact-target-rest-api-task-in-salesforce-to-track-mail)

ok now got to know that its not tracked on Task, but an record under an object  "Individual     Email Result" is created and tracks the below fields
[image]

```
    Email Name :ettest
    Lead :Test Test, Test Test
    From Name : Pravin 
    From Address :xxxx@cccc.com 
    Subject Line    :ettest 
    Date Sent   :2/12/2014 1:41 AM Opened : Not Checked Date Opened 
    Date Unsubscribed    
    Number of Total Clicks  :0 
    Date Bounced: Number of Unique Clicks   :0 
    Link "View Sent Email" all this is tracked.
```

how can we do the same for triggered send email from sf

Any Suggestions How to create this record and from where can i get this values and how to update the when its opened along with the no of times clicked

Comment: View sent email opens up the page in Exact Target the exact mail sent to the subscriber

Answer (score 1):

I added the below ampscript
mentioned details are captured but view sent email dose not work.
ET page in SF Displays JOB ID Missing any suggestions

```
     %%[ var @id
     set @id=CreateSalesforceObject("xtma_Individual_Email_Result__c", 7, "Name", emailname_, "From_Address__c",OwnerEmail,"From_Name__c",OwnerFullName,"Subject_Line__c",EmailSubject,"Opportunity__c",Whoid," Email__c",view_email_url,"RecordTypeId","01260000000Jxxx"
     )
     ]%%
```

Comment: Is this the a best practice.

Comment: I have not seen this use-case before, typically the Individual Email Result objects are only created by the integration, not manually using AMPscript.  Is the email send that you are creating the Individual Email Results records one that was sent through the ExactTarget Integration with Salesforce?  If not, then I believe there is going to be some metadata missing within ExactTarget that  relates the Id of the Email Result from Salesforce with the JobID in ExactTarget which is required for that link to work.

Comment: Thanks Mac, to take a look at it. Yes it is sent from exact target integration in salesforce. but its a Triggered Send Using Rest API. In common practice in SF when we send an ET email for lead/contact through the standard ET App, the mail sent is recorded in (IER)Individual EmailResult. But doing the same using a triggred send Fails to track the mails. As a work arround we have created a new field in IER which captures the link %%view_email_url%%. this solves the use case but seems a kind of tricky.

Comment: Seems like a good workaround, but really looking for a more authoritative answer as to how we should be addressing this

Comment: @Kelly J Andrews , Thanks for Reviewing the Workaround. Still Open for a solution with best practice. By This approach I am Experiencing Delays in Sending emails. ie mails are in Queue for a long time. is this because of the DML Operation ? in each Individual mail. Please share your ideas if any. Thanks.

Comment: Going to give you the bounty here for at least the efforts.  In regards to the queue, sending is based on time of day and other emails in the queue.  It can take some time if there are other emails going out that are substantial.  What's your typical wait times?